# How can I track the status of installation of an application using Sikuli

Tags: sikuli

I am using Sikuli to automate the process of installing a downloaded application on the Mac.  The installation includes an add-on that also gets installed.  *e.g.* While installing Adobe Reader, McAfee Security Scan gets installed as an add-on:

[image]

How can I track the status of the two installations individually?

If this is not possible with Sikuli, please suggest any other ways that I could do this.

Comment: What problem do you have exactly with sikuli? You can check both %s and see your app and add-on install progress.

Comment: Hii.. am new to Sikuli, currently i have used Sikuli to automate the process of Installation on MAc, I need to check the progress bar info for every 2sec like which app is installing faster, I did not get %s what yo've mentioned in the comment, Pls elaborate the same.

Comment: pls respond how to use sikuli to track the progress

Comment: HAve you tried locating the App names ("Adobe Reader" and "McAfee Security scan plus"), and then seach on the right to find() for a "100%"? If you find the "100%" the app is installed, else you wait 1 second and retry